# Rubbing of wood on a rough surface

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to know the word or phrase for rubbing a piece of wood on a stone or a rough surface to get a paste.
Example Sandalwood emits fragrance only when it is ------(fill) on a stone.
Or shall we say Sandalwood emits fragrance only when it wears out?

Comment: @NigelJ Using a workshop [grindstone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grindstone) to sharpen a tool or shape a piece of metal is called grinding and involves pressing the workpiece against the surface of a rotating stone. It doesn't involve crushing the workpiece.

Comment: In addition to grind -- mill, file, roughen, roughen up.

Answer (score 4):

The only word I can think of is `ground` - this is the word that you would use when turning corn into flour, (grinding or milling) which is a very similar activity.

Comment: Thank You. But doesn't  grinding or milling suggests a dry powder, whereas I look for a wet smooth paste? Or can we use the word 'grind' like that of 'wet grinder' ?

Answer (score 2):

The word I would use is ***abrade***, so

'Sandalwood emits fragrance only when it is *abraded* on a stone'

[Definition from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abrade):

> to rub or wear away especially by friction

Comment: Technically correct, but much too formal for most circumstances.

Comment: @MikeBrockington it won't be at all formal for people who extract perfume from sandalwood!